# Is audio recording possible using Apple Watch Simulator?

Tags: objective-c, watchkit, audio-recording, simulator, apple-watch

I am trying to create audio recording functionality using Apple Watch Simulator(Watch OS 2 beta). But I am getting following error while calling **presentAudioRecorderControllerWithOutputURL**.

Error: *Error Domain=com.apple.watchkit.errors Code=3 "(null)"*

```
-(void)didSelectRowWithTag:(NSInteger)tag
 {
     NSString*strPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
     NSString *strAudioFileName = [strPath stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%d.caf",tag]];
     NSURL *urlOutPut = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:strAudioFileName];
     NSDictionary *dictMaxAudioRec = @{@"WKAudioRecorderControllerOptionsMaximumDurationKey":@1800};

    [self presentAudioRecorderControllerWithOutputURL:urlOutPut preset:WKAudioRecorderPresetHighQualityAudio options:dictMaxAudioRec completion:^(BOOL didSave, NSError * error) {
        if(didSave)
        {
            NSLog(@"File Saved....");
        }

        NSLog(@"%@",error);
    }];
}
```

Comment: Above code sample worked fine if you change the file format from ".caf" to ".wav", ".mp4" or ".m4a" as mentioned below by @lostAtSeaJoshua

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Watchkit error code 3 is Watchkit invalid argument error. It looks like the error could be in your output file path. You are appending it with name .caf which is not a supported type of audio file output. From the documentation it states for the URL parameter:

> The URL at which to store the recorded output. The filename extension determines the type of audio to record. You may specify the extensions .wav, .mp4, and .m4a.

Here is example code that works to record audio.

```
let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0]  
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path.stringByAppendingPathComponent("dictation.wav"))  
self.presentAudioRecordingControllerWithOutputURL(url, preset: WKAudioRecordingPreset.NarrowBandSpeech, maximumDuration: 30, actionTitle: "Save") { (didSave, error) -> Void in  
if let error = error {  
    print("error: \(error)")  
    return  
}  

if didSave {  
    print("saved!")  
    }  
}
```

With this fix I am still not sure that the simulator will support audio recording. The simulator does not support every API call and you may need a real watch to test. Please update us with result.

Comment: Thanks .. It really helped. The actual problem was ".caf" file format. After I changed it to ".m4a" it opens AudioRecordingController in Apple Watch simulator as well. I got the recorded audio file using simulator **but** because of **Hardware(microphone) Limitation in simulator**, i can not hear the Audio.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, I don't think the other answers are as complete or correct  as this one (WatchOS 2.1, Jan. 2016):

```
func recordAudio(){
        let duration = NSTimeInterval(5)
        let recordOptions =
        [WKAudioRecorderControllerOptionsMaximumDurationKey : duration]
        //CONSTRUCT AUDIO FILE URL
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let container = fileManager.containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.artificialsolutions.applewatch")
        let fileName = "audio.wav"
        saveUrl = container?.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
        presentAudioRecorderControllerWithOutputURL(saveUrl!,
            preset: .NarrowBandSpeech,
            options: recordOptions,
            completion: { saved, error in
                if let err = error {
                    print(err.description)
                }
                if saved {
                    print("Audio Saved")
                }
        })
    }
```